# Fragment button causes backstack error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I am trying to create an app that will get some information from a server, using volley. You should enter your info in, and then click login at the bottom, but for somereason it keeps crashing.

First and foremost when the button is clicked, it crashes and the logcat is:
https://pastebin.com/deQi874r

Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentFragDisplay);
    textView.setText("My Profile");

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Personal_Profile_Fragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int item_id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item_id) {
        case R.id.accDetails:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.personalProfileLookup:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.favoriteCharacters:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.friendProfileLookup:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.tipsAndTricks:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;

    }
    return false;
}

private void swapFragment(int fragmentID){

    TextView tracker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentFragDisplay);

    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(fragmentID == R.id.personalProfileLookup) {
        tracker.setText("My Profile");
        fragment = new Personal_Profile_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.favoriteCharacters) {
        tracker.setText("Favorite Characters");
        fragment = new Favorite_Characters_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.friendProfileLookup) {
        tracker.setText("Friend Lookup");
        fragment = new Friend_Profile_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.tipsAndTricks) {
        tracker.setText("Tips and Tricks");
        fragment = new TipsandTricks_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.accDetails) {
        tracker.setText("Log In");
        fragment = new loginFragment();
    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

login fragment(where button is):

```
public class loginFragment extends Fragment {

//Local Vars
private boolean loginCheck = false;

//required constructor
public loginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            login(v);
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;

}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loginCheck;
}



private void login(View v){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    String username;
    String password;

    username = v.findViewById(R.id.enteredUsername).toString();
    password = v.findViewById(R.id.enteredPassword).toString();

    final ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] unameSeparated = new String[username.length()];
    unameSeparated = username.split("(?!^)");

    String startUrl = "https://us.api.battle.net/d3/profile/";
    String uname = "";
    String APIKey = "/?locale=en_US&apikey=6nguxckrzchn86q9792jvdhww4uxf32v";

    //Separating the username into the parts needed for sending request
    for (int i = 0; i < unameSeparated.length; i++) {
        if ((unameSeparated[i].equals("#"))) {
            //Replacing # with '%23'
            uname += "%23";
        } else {
            uname += unameSeparated[i];
        }
    }

    String url = startUrl + uname+ APIKey;

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    info.add(response);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Request Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Request FAIL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Comment: That's what I dont understand, it only occurs when you click on the button. I dont understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with you login click. You are passing the button and not the view in

```
login(v);
```

The `V` you are passing is  an instance of the button not the view. So this

```
username = v.findViewById(R.id.enteredUsername).toString();
password = v.findViewById(R.id.enteredPassword).toString();
```

would be refering to a null pointer. Hope this helps

Comment: I fixed it by instead of doing login(v); I did login(getView()); and it seems to be working so far.